# Append out from reading lines in a txt file

Tags: bash, sh

I have a test.txt file with the following contents

```
100001
100003
100007
100008
100009
```

I am trying to loop through the text file and append each one with .xml.

Ex:

```
100001.xml
100003.xml
100007.xml
100008.xml
100009.xml
```

I have tried different variations of

```
while read p; do
echo "$p.zip"
done < test.txt
```

But it prints out weird like this

```
.xml01
.xml03
.xml07
.xml08
.xml09
```

Comment: Does your test.txt file have Windows style CRLF line endings but you're in an environment that expects Unix style LF line endings?

Comment: Your code works on my end, but note you're appending ".zip" instead of ".xml". It might be an issue of line endings as @Shawn suggests. You can try using `dos2unix` on the file to convert it

Comment: This will be ran in linux (debian) environment. The .zip was a typo, should be .xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending a `.xml` at the end of each line while removing CRLF, if present.

- With `sed` and bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sed -E $'s/\r?$/.xml/' test.txt
```

- With `awk`:

```sh
awk -v suffix='.xml' '{sub(/\r?$/,suffix)}1' test.txt
```

###### Using it in a bash loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r filename
do
    printf '%q\n' "$filename"
done < <(
    awk -v suffix='.xml' '{sub(/\r?$/,suffix)}1' test.txt
)
```

---

Or doing the whole thing in pure shell:

```sh
while IFS='' read -r filename
do
    fullname="${filename%\r}.xml"
    printf '%s\n' "$fullname"
done < test.txt
```

Comment: These work. Thanks.